# Intellisense Not Working SSMS 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I know there are a lot of posts on this issue, however I am unable to find a resolution to my issues.

Running: 
SMS 2014 with CU1 - Version 10.0.2342.0 on both SSMS and Client Tools.
Visual Studio 2010 SP1 - 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Connecting to:
Server 2008 R2 SP2 CU 5 - 10.50.4276

Have Verified:
IntelliSense in enabled.
SQLCMD Mode is disabled.
Have Refreshed Cache.
Verified IntelliSense settings.
Server does not support contained databases so this was ruled out.

Behavior:

- When connected to the Master database

Intellisense autopopulates and functions normally. All the tables are listed and the additional databases on the server.

- When connected to a non-system database

Neither parameters or tables autopopulate and CTRL-J does not do anything.

Anyone have any other ideas to try?  SSMS 2008 R2 worked fine across all the databases.

Comment: IIRC SSMS Intellisense has *never* worked when connected to a down-version server/database.

Comment: Hope that's not the case, but will just downgrade back to 2008R2 if so.

Comment: I just install several different versions of SSMS to address this.  As long as the SSMS version matches the SQL Server version it should work.

Comment: Going from SSMS 2014 to Server 2012 SP1 11.0.3000 works fine with IntelliSense.  So assuming it's either a compatibility issue to 2008 R2 or a config server side which I am not able to change.

Comment: Even if the provide down-level support for Intellisense, it's likely that they limit how many versions back they will support.

Answer (score 1):

You could try refreshing the local cache by pressing CTRL + Shift + R buttons and wait for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Offline Linked Server can cause such behavior. Reconfigure or remove unreachable Linked server(s) and refresh Intellisense Local Cache with Ctrl+Shift+R.

Background of this solution: If your database has objects referencing offline Linked server, Intellisense is waiting for a resource which can't update and stops working.