# Intellisense not working in sql server 2014 for azure database but working when connected to local DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, sql-server-2014, intellisense

I recently upgraded my SSMS 2014 Express to SP1 and then after up-gradation, IntelliSense is not working when I connect to my Azure database.
But when I connect to my local DB it works fine.

I've tried below options also but didn't resolve the issue.

Under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense` it says it is enabled there.

Under `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`

Go to `Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General >> IntelliSense`
Select Auto List Members and Check Parameter Information.

[Intellisense not working in SSMS 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438341/intellisense-is-not-working-in-sql-server-2014)

[Intellisense not working SSMS 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970797/intellisense-not-working-ssms-2014?rq=1)

All the above options I've tried in my SSMS 2014 but still, I'm facing the issue.

See below image, when I connect to Azure DB IntelliSense option in disabled.
[image]

Comment: SSMS 17.2 is free (just as free as Express), and the latest version has intellisense for Azure  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid so IntelliSense will not work for azure db in ssms 2014?

Comment: That I don't know. But I do know that Azure intellisense _doesnt_ work in 17.1 but it _does_ in 17.2. If you want an SSMS that connects to sql 2014 and has working Azure intellisense then 17.2 will do that.